# How to make multi-languages in discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have en.json and ru.json files, I use variables by type there:

```
levelupmessage: "Congratulations on the new $ {level}"
```

**because in json you cannot put `` what needs to be done so that there is not just a string?**

Comment: Are you asking how to escape backticks in JSON?

Comment: Yes,i am asking how to escape backticks in JSON

Comment: JSON allows unescaped backticks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a module that loads all messages from `en.json` and `ru.json` and saves them in an object.
Then, create a function that finds the specified string inside your object. This function also replaces `%VAR%` with a parameter you pass to that function.

Take a look at this example:

```js
let strings = {
   en: {
      // I prefer % for variables
      levelUp: "Congratulations on leveling up: %VAR%"
   },
   ru: {
      levelUp: "Поздравляем с новым уровнем: %VAR%"
   }
};

// Function to get locales and replace variables
function getLocale(language, string, ...vars) {
   let locale = strings[language][string];

   let count = 0;
   locale = locale.replace(/%VAR%/g, () => vars[count] !== null ? vars[count] : "%VAR%");

   return locale;
}

getLocale("en", "levelUp", "10");   // Congratulations on leveling up: 10
getLocale("ru", "levelUp", "10");   // Поздравляем с новым уровнем: 10
```

That's how many popular Discord bots handle internationalization.